# Need help for multiple foreach statements in php

Tags: php, foreach

Could you please tell me how to write foreach loops for the arrray below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sector] => Agriculture
            [experience] => 2
            [first_name] => ranjith
            [second_name] => 
            [position] => 
            [telephone] => 442254322
            [mobile] => 999999999
            [email] => dfd@gmail.com
            [education] => Phd
            [resume] => 
            [photograph] => 
            [comments] => goodsdsdfdfd
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [sector] => Water
            [experience] => 3
            [first_name] => jagdish
            [second_name] => 
            [position] => 
            [telephone] => 99999
            [mobile] => 99
            [email] => jag@gmail.com
            [education] => sdsdf
            [resume] => 
            [photograph] => 
            [comments] => sdfsdf
            [status] => 0
        )
     )
```

Comment: need to get first_name or second_name

Comment: have you tried something? can you be more precise?

Comment: Thanks for solution .This is what i was expecting

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key == 'first_name')
        {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your just looking for the first and second name values, I assume to populate a full name

```
foreach ($arr as $item) 
{
    $name = $item['first_name'];
    $name .= $item['second_name'] != '' ? ' '.$item['second_name'] : '';
    echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    foreach($v as $kk=>$vv)
        echo "$kk for $k is $vv\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To output it?

```
foreach($data as $record) {
    foreach($record as $k => $v) {
        echo $k.":".$v
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $item)
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key == 'first_name')
            echo $value; // print the firstname
        elseif($key == 'second_name')
            echo $value; // print the second name
    }
```